# Using Windows bash as the shell

Tags: spacemacs, bash

I'm trying get Spacemacs (i.e., Emacs) to use the Windows subsystem for Linux bash shell as the shell.

I've added `(setq explicit-shell-file-name "c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe")` to my .spacemacs configuration file, but when I enter:

`SPC SPC ansi-term`

and answer yes, it returns:

`Spawning child process: invalid argument`.

Is there a way to get Emacs to run bash (i.e., the Windows subsystem for Linux) as the shell?

Comment: I can't test it right now without getting to a Windows machine, but I strongly suspect the issue is that `bash.exe` is not actually the Bash shell, but the terminal emulator that Windows opens Bash inside of; Emacs can't open it for redirection because it isn't a program taking standard input and output. The first workaround that comes to me would be to enable sshd access into Bash on a high port (I use 2222) and use an `ssh localhost:2222` command instead. If you're unsure how to do this, let me know and I'll dig up the relevant docs.